# jQuery how to bind all anchors in a div

Tags: jquery, html, events

I have a problem to bind a click event on each `<a>` on this div:

```
<div id="box_list_menu" class="boxlistmenu">
    <a href="/profile/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/grantAccessToPrivatePhotos/index.php?tid=${ID}&un=${Name}" id="${ID}_grantAccessPrivatephotos" rel="link" class="boxlistmenu_grantaccessprivatephotos" title="Donner accès à vos photos privées"></a>
    <a href="/profile/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/denyAccessToPrivatePhotos/index.php?tid=${ID}&un=${Name}" id="${ID}_denyAccessPrivatephotos" rel="link" class="boxlistmenu_denyaccessprivatephotos" title="Retirer l'accès à vos photos privées"></a>
    <a href="/profile/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/block/index.php?tid=${ID}" id="${ID}_unblock" rel="link" class="boxlistmenu_block" title="Bloquer ce membre"></a>
    <a href="/profile/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/unblock/index.php?tid=${ID}" id="${ID}_block" rel="link" class="boxlistmenu_unblock" title="Débloquer ce membre"></a>
    <a href="/profile/report/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001/index.php?tid=${ID}&un=${Name}" rel="link" class="boxlistmenu_report" title="Signaler ce profil à un administrateur"></a>
</div>
```

This is my jquery code:

```
container.find('#box_list_menu:a').bind("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var t = this.id.split("_");
    var profileID = t[0];
    var action = t[1];
    var btn = $(this);
    btn.trigger("blur").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("inactive").find("b").html(bscTexts.search.pleaseWait);
    alert("boxlist_menu action = " +action+ " e = " +e);
    switch (action) {
        case "block":
            bsc.event.addListener(bsc.menu.listenerTypes.block, "profile", function (e) {
                $("#" + profileID + "_block").hide();
                $("#" + profileID + "_unblock").show();

                btn.removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("inactive").find("b").html(btn.attr("title"));
            });
            bsc.menu.BlockProfile(e, profileID);
            break;
        case "unblock":
            bsc.event.addListener(bsc.menu.listenerTypes.unblock, "profile", function (e) {
                $("#" + profileID + "_unblock").hide();
                $("#" + profileID + "_block").show();
btn.removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("inactive").find("b").html(btn.attr("title"));
            });
            bsc.menu.UnblockProfile(e, profileID);
            break;
        case "grantAccessPrivatephotos":
            bsc.event.addListener(bsc.menu.listenerTypes.grantAccessPrivatephotos, "profile", function (e) {
                $("#" + profileID + "_grantAccessPrivatephotos").hide();
                $("#" + profileID + "_denyAccessPrivatephotos").show();
btn.removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("inactive").find("b").html(btn.attr("title"));
            });
            bsc.menu.GrantAccessToPrivatePhotos(e, profileID);
            break;
        case "denyAccessPrivatephotos":
            bsc.event.addListener(bsc.menu.listenerTypes.denyAccessPrivatephotos, "profile", function (e) {
                $("#" + profileID + "_denyAccessPrivatephotos").hide();
                $("#" + profileID + "_grantAccessPrivatephotos").show();
btn.removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("inactive").find("b").html(btn.attr("title"));
            });
            bsc.menu.DenyAccessToPrivatePhotos(e, profileID);
            break;
        default:
    }
    return false;
});
```

only the a href is execute, never enter on container.find my alert popup never open, the switch case never execute and my addListener never added !

Thank you very much for your helping

Comment: you said you have problem, what is it? doesnt your codes work? return error or what?? please update the question.

Comment: Only a href open the page and never my alert popup, my switch case never entered and never my addListener is add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be your selector, `box_list_menu:a`. This will select any `box_list_menu` elements that satisfy the `:a` psuedoclass (which doesn't exist in css or in jQuery). What you want select any `a` elements under element with the id `box_list_menu`.

Use this instead

```
container.find('#box_list_menu a').bind(...)
```

Or just

```
$('#box_list_menu a').bind(...)
```

Notice the space between `#box_list_menu` and `a` -- this means to select `a` elements that are descendants of `#box_list_menu`.

**Further Reading**

- [Selectors | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: @LiTHiUM2525 notice the space between the `#box_list_menu` and the `a`. That's critical. Your latest edit still has a colon instead of a space.

Comment: where you see a space between ?? i have a : not a space

Comment: @LiTHiUM2525 yes, that's the problem.

Comment: when i use : container.find('#box_list_menu a').bind(...) i obtain : ReferenceError: container is not defined

Comment: @LiTHiUM2525 Try replacing `container.find(...)` with `$(...)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27678/discussion-between-lithium2525-and-p-s-w-g)

Answer (score 2):

You you are using jquery >= 1.7, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('#box_list_menu').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    //Do whatever you want
})
```

Comment: just a secund i try this !